# reading in C++ a socket open by Java + structure alignment

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, boost-asio

I am trying to write in Linnux a client in C++ using `boost::asio` data from a socket. The server is built in Java. The issue I have now is that I cannot read correctly some piece of information from the socket. If the client is done in JAVA everything is ok.

In details the big error I have are in receiving the `unsigned long` and the `int` in the structure below. I am expectng a value for `anInteger` should be `0x00000005` so 5, but reading from the socket gives me `0x03000` ( ?!?! ). It is definetely a different number and based on the hexadecimal printing I have less digits( ?!?!? ).

For `aUnLong` I should receive something approaching to a number 1279272977799 so in hex is `0x129DA9C8587`, instead a receive something like `0x00129ffffffdaffffff8fffffff9f5c`. I see that some piece of information is good but it is mixed with all `ff`s  and where I don't know where they come from.

I am guaranteed to receive each time 168 bytes ( so fixed number of bytes ). 
In the beginning I though about the data alignment of my structure so I introduced `attribute((packed))`.

The `label` and `lbl_2` are string; I now that JAVA uses UTF but it is not clear to me how this play in this scenario.

Can you help me with this issue?

I thank you very much.

EO

```
union MyStruct
{
    char buffer[168];

    struct _data{
        char            dash[2];    
        unsigned long   aUnLong;
        char            label[128]; 
        char            lbl_2[24];  
        int         anInteger;  
    } __attribute__((__packed__));

    _data data; // the real data
};
```

Reading happens using this simple line

```
MyStruct obj;
size_t reply_length = asio::read( s,asio::buffer(obj.buffer, 168));
```

this is the original format sent out

```
byte 000,001: #
byte 002-010: aLong (8 byte) long - milliseconds since 1-1-1970 in UTC
byte 011-139: label (128 byte 2byte per character) label_1
byte 140-164: lbl2 (24 byte 2byte per character) label2 code
byte 165-169: anInteger (4 byte) integer
```

Comment: It is difficult to offer any help without knowing what protocol and/or serialisation format the Java server is using.

Comment: We need to know the format of the messages the Java server sends.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure doesn't appear to be 168 bytes on common systems. If `long` is 4 bytes (typical in 32-bit compilation) then your struct is probably 162 or 164 if packed isn't honored. If `long` is 8 bytes, then 164 or 168 (if padded, which as you surmise is bad).

Check the `sizeof(_data)` in your program and see what the compiler tells you it is.

Also, your original format information is confusing. For example you say "byte 002-010: aLong (8 byte) long", but bytes 2-10 are NINE (9) bytes not 8. Is there a crc or checksum byte?